# Eclipse Compare Editor that Shows Changes In Single Panel

Tags: eclipse, plugins

Is there a way to compare changes done to a file in a single panel like [Trac does](http://www.hermann-uwe.de/files/images/trac.preview.jpg) rather than show the changes side by side?

Answer (score 1):

Not by default in Eclipse, however you can use the [External Diff](http://sourceforge.net/projects/externaldiff/) plugin to use any external diff application that you would like.